# Passing data from popup to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, popup

i have a basic form where the users of an ERP can create ticket for quick support. In the form they have to put the client ID, but i want them to click a search icon to open a pop up (or something similar) and select the client.

[image: cliente form]

In the pop up i want to load a list of client, and when they select the client, send de ID to the main page where they are creating the ticket...

How can i do this?

Comment: Please specify how to display the list of users. If you will use drop down (select element), you can use onchange JS function.

Comment: You can also use localStorage.

Comment: You can use something like Bootstrap's Modal to open a pop-up within the same page, or just open a new window using JavaScript. The new window can call methods on the parent page, that's how you would pass back the client ID.

Comment: i will display a table with "usefull" information, and for example i can add a check box so they can check and then and select or define the client name like <a> so when they click de name the inputs autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I use the next script to send data from child to main page:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    window.opener.document.getElementById('cliente-nombre').value = data;
    window.parent.close();
  });
```

and in the button wich open the popup:

```
function openNominaCliente() {
     window.open("/clientes/nomina", "popupId", "location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,width=500,height=500"); 
     }
```

Thanks all!